# Weird random errors, java drawing

Tags: java

I have written a program which I think ought to work flawlessly. For some reason it doesn't. I will provide the code and hope that somebody can figure out what's wrong. I've been sitting with it for hours but I can't get any further.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CrystalModel
{
    private int radius;
    private int index;
    private boolean[][] crystal;
    private Point concludingPoint;
    private int escapeRadius;

    /**
     * Constructor. Initiates an electron bath of size 30x30.
     */
    public CrystalModel()
    {
        radius = 30;
        index = 30*2-1;
        start();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor. Initiates an electron bath of size r.
     * @param r bath radius
     */
    public CrystalModel(int r)
    {
        radius = r;
        index = r*2-1;
        start();
    }

    /**
     * Initiates the experiment
     */
    private void start()
    {
        crystal = new boolean[radius*2][radius*2];
        crystal[radius][radius] = true; //The width is always even (2*r), this is as close to the center as one gets
        escapeRadius = (int)(1.1*radius);
    }

    /**
     * Determines if a given xy-coordinate is within radius
     * @param x x-coordinate
     * @param y y-coordinate
     * @return whether the active ion is out of range
     */
    private boolean outsideCircle(int r, int x, int y)
    {
        return (Math.pow(x,2)+Math.pow(y,2) >= Math.pow(r, 2));
    }

    /**
     * Determines if the currently active ion has a neighbouring crystallized ion
     * @param whether the is a neighbour
     */
    private boolean anyNeighbours(int x, int y)
    {
            x = xBathToModel(x);
            y = yBathToModel(y);

            boolean left    = (x-1 >= 0) && (x-1 <= index) && (y >= 0) && (y <= index)  ? crystal[x-1][y] : false;
            boolean right   = (x+1 >= 0) && (x+1 <= index) && (y >= 0) && (y <= index)  ? crystal[x+1][y] : false;
            boolean up      = (y-1 >= 0) && (y-1 <= index) && (x >= 0) && (x <= index)  ? crystal[x][y-1] : false;
            boolean down    = (y+1 >= 0) && (y+1 <= index) && (x >= 0) && (x <= index)  ? crystal[x][y+1] : false;

            return ( left || right || up || down );
    }

    /**
     * Determines an xy-coordinate at radius distance from the center
     * @param radius radius of escape for ions
     * @return Point object encapsulating x, y
     */
    private Point dropNewIon()
    {
        double angle = (int)(Math.random()*2*Math.PI);
        return new Point( (int)( Math.cos(angle)*(index/2) ), (int)( Math.sin(angle)*(index/2) ) );
    }

    /**
     * Transform x-coordinate upon the moving of origo from center to top-left
     * @ x x-coordinate
     */
    public int xBathToModel(int x)
    {
        return radius+x;
    }

    /**
     * Transform y-coordinate upon the moving of origo from center to top-left
     * @param y y-coordinate
     */
    public int yBathToModel(int y)
    {
        return radius+y;
    }

    /**
     * Increments the number of ions in the crystal by one
     * @return boolean indicating whether the experiment is done or not
     */
    private Point crystallizeOneIon()
    {
        Point point = dropNewIon();
        for( ; ; )
        {
            switch((int)(Math.random()*4+1))
            {
                case 1: point.x+=1;
                    break;
                case 2: point.x-=1;
                    break;
                case 3: point.y+=1;
                    break;
                case 4: point.y-=1;
                    break;
            }

            if(outsideCircle(escapeRadius, point.x, point.y)) point = dropNewIon();

            if(anyNeighbours(point.x, point.y)) break;
        }

        crystal[xBathToModel(point.x)][yBathToModel(point.y)] = true;
        return point;
    }

    /**
     * Let the algorithm (CrystalExperiment) simulate a number of steps
     * @param steps how many steps
     * @return boolean indiciating whether the experiment is concluded
     */
    public boolean runExperiment(int steps)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<steps; i++)
        {
            concludingPoint = crystallizeOneIon();

            if(outsideCircle((int)index/2, concludingPoint.x, concludingPoint.y)) 
            {
                concludingPoint.x = xBathToModel(concludingPoint.x);
                concludingPoint.y = yBathToModel(concludingPoint.y);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                concludingPoint.x = xBathToModel(concludingPoint.x);
                concludingPoint.y = yBathToModel(concludingPoint.y);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Return a textual representation of the crystal
     * @return String representing the crystal
     */
    public String toString()
    {
        String output = "";
        for(int y=-1; y<=index+1; y++)
        {
            for(int x=-1; x<=index+1; x++)
            {
                if(y == -1) output+="--";
                else if(y == index+1) output+="--";
                else
                {
                    if(x == -1) output+="|";
                    else if(x == index+1) output+="|";
                    else
                    {
                        if(concludingPoint.equals(new Point(x,y))) output+="# ";
                        else if(crystal[x][y] == true) output+="* ";
                        else output+="  ";
                    }
                }
            }
            output+="\n";
        }

        return output;
    }

    public int getIndexSize()
    {
        return index;
    }

    public boolean getMatrixValue(int x, int y)
    {
        return crystal[x][y];
    }

    private void drawCrystal()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);

        CrystalView drawing = new CrystalView(this);
        frame.add(drawing);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        (new CrystalModel(200)).drawCrystal();
    }

}
```

This is my view, it doesn't work (although the toString method works, and this is similar):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class CrystalView extends JPanel
{
    CrystalModel model;
    public CrystalView(CrystalModel m)
    {
        model = m;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        while(!model.runExperiment(1))
        {
            for(int y=0; y<model.getIndexSize(); y++)
            {
                for(int x=0; x<model.getIndexSize(); x++)
                {
                    if(model.getMatrixValue(x,y))
                    g.drawOval(x, y, 1, 1);
                }
            }
            this.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

The error is in the drawing. It (1) generates errors in the terminal, and (2) doesn't draw a full size. Please run the program and you will see what I mean.

Comment: *"Please run the program and you will see what I mean."*.  No, I won't.  If you want some help you need to put in some effort to tell us what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is very simple. If you look at the for-loop it loops through 1-200 for example, and fills in pixels at within this area (200x200). But if you draw it, the figure becomes very small. If it draws at all, that is. With a size of just 200px it will freeze entirely, so I suppose I'm doing something that slows it down.

Comment: Also, just focus on the drawing part because I have already verified that the model works. toString returns a correct image of what the graphics should look like as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{ 
    while(!model.runExperiment(1)) 
    { 
        for(int y=0; y<model.getIndexSize(); y++) 
        { 
            for(int x=0; x<model.getIndexSize(); x++) 
            { 
                if(model.getMatrixValue(x,y)) 
                g.drawOval(x, y, 1, 1); 
            } 
        } 
        this.repaint(); 
    } 
}
```

I don't know what the code should do but you should never have a loop that invokes repaint() like that. that is one way to cause an infinite loop.

If you are trying to animate something then you need to use a Thread or a Swing Timer to do the animation.

Comment: Basically, the picture I'm drawing builds up incrementally. For each time I run "runExperiment" the matrix gets a new value. So I have to do the loops again, to draw everything up. As a result, there should be little animation where one can see the image getting larger... but I have no need for a timer or something like that. I am almost 100% certain that this was somehow the intended solution.

Comment: That loop definitely doesn't belong there. repaint will cause paintComponent to be called again, etc.. What you want is just the contents of that loop, and a timer that repeatedly calls `model.runExperiment(1)` and `repaint()`.

Comment: The paintComponent() method is used to paint the current state of the component. If you want to change the state of the component then you have other methods to do so. That is you have a Timer or something to invoke the method that changes the state of the component and then that method invokes repaint().

Comment: @Calle, check out the example by Walter Lan that shows how to use a Timer to change the state of a component by invoking the "addPoint()" method: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2139875&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

I tried to fix your code (see below). The problem place is marked with TODO. Don't know how is it intended to work, but now it draws some points.

As mentioned in previous answer you can't get animation like this. The `paintComponent()` method is only called once to draw the component. This happens when the form is resized for example. So you can get only static image.

CrystalModel.java

```
import java.awt.Point;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class CrystalModel
{
    private int radius;
    private int index;
    private boolean[][] crystal;
    private Point concludingPoint;
    private int escapeRadius;

    /**
     * Constructor. Initiates an electron bath of size 30x30.
     */
    public CrystalModel()
    {
        radius = 30;
        index = 30*2-1;
        start();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor. Initiates an electron bath of size r.
     * @param r bath radius
     */
    public CrystalModel(int r)
    {
        radius = r;
        index = r*2-1;
        start();
    }

    /**
     * Initiates the experiment
     */
    private void start()
    {
        crystal = new boolean[radius*2][radius*2];
        crystal[radius][radius] = true; //The width is always even (2*r), this is as close to the center as one gets
        escapeRadius = (int)(1.1*radius);
    }

    /**
     * Determines if a given xy-coordinate is within radius
     * @param x x-coordinate
     * @param y y-coordinate
     * @return whether the active ion is out of range
     */
    private boolean outsideCircle(int r, int x, int y)
    {
        return (Math.pow(x,2)+Math.pow(y,2) >= Math.pow(r, 2));
    }

    /**
     * Determines if the currently active ion has a neighbouring crystallized ion
     * @param whether the is a neighbour
     */
    private boolean anyNeighbours(int x, int y)
    {
            x = xBathToModel(x);
            y = yBathToModel(y);

            boolean left    = (x-1 >= 0) && (x-1 <= index) && (y >= 0) && (y <= index)  ? crystal[x-1][y] : false;
            boolean right   = (x+1 >= 0) && (x+1 <= index) && (y >= 0) && (y <= index)  ? crystal[x+1][y] : false;
            boolean up      = (y-1 >= 0) && (y-1 <= index) && (x >= 0) && (x <= index)  ? crystal[x][y-1] : false;
            boolean down    = (y+1 >= 0) && (y+1 <= index) && (x >= 0) && (x <= index)  ? crystal[x][y+1] : false;

            return ( left || right || up || down );
    }

    /**
     * Determines an xy-coordinate at radius distance from the center
     * @param radius radius of escape for ions
     * @return Point object encapsulating x, y
     */
    private Point dropNewIon()
    {
        double angle = (int)(Math.random()*2*Math.PI);
        return new Point( (int)( Math.cos(angle)*(index/2) ), (int)( Math.sin(angle)*(index/2) ) );
    }

    /**
     * Transform x-coordinate upon the moving of origo from center to top-left
     * @ x x-coordinate
     */
    public int xBathToModel(int x)
    {
        return radius+x;
    }

    /**
     * Transform y-coordinate upon the moving of origo from center to top-left
     * @param y y-coordinate
     */
    public int yBathToModel(int y)
    {
        return radius+y;
    }

    /**
     * Increments the number of ions in the crystal by one
     * @return boolean indicating whether the experiment is done or not
     */
    private Point crystallizeOneIon()
    {
        Point point = dropNewIon();
        for( ; ; )
        {
            switch((int)(Math.random()*4+1))
            {
                case 1: point.x+=1;
                    break;
                case 2: point.x-=1;
                    break;
                case 3: point.y+=1;
                    break;
                case 4: point.y-=1;
                    break;
            }

            if(outsideCircle(escapeRadius, point.x, point.y)) point = dropNewIon();

            if(anyNeighbours(point.x, point.y)) break;
            break;
        }

        try {
            // TODO The logic is wrong here - calculated points sometimes are out of array. See console output
            crystal[xBathToModel(point.x)][yBathToModel(point.y)] = true;
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Oops, point (" + point.x + ", " + point.y +  ") is out of array");
        }
        return point;
    }

    /**
     * Let the algorithm (CrystalExperiment) simulate a number of steps
     * @param steps how many steps
     * @return boolean indiciating whether the experiment is concluded
     */
    public synchronized boolean runExperiment(int steps)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<steps; i++)
        {
            concludingPoint = crystallizeOneIon();

            if(outsideCircle((int)index/2, concludingPoint.x, concludingPoint.y))
            {
                concludingPoint.x = xBathToModel(concludingPoint.x);
                concludingPoint.y = yBathToModel(concludingPoint.y);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                concludingPoint.x = xBathToModel(concludingPoint.x);
                concludingPoint.y = yBathToModel(concludingPoint.y);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Return a textual representation of the crystal
     * @return String representing the crystal
     */
    public String toString()
    {
        String output = "";
        for(int y=-1; y<=index+1; y++)
        {
            for(int x=-1; x<=index+1; x++)
            {
                if(y == -1) output+="--";
                else if(y == index+1) output+="--";
                else
                {
                    if(x == -1) output+="|";
                    else if(x == index+1) output+="|";
                    else
                    {
                        if(concludingPoint.equals(new Point(x,y))) output+="# ";
                        else if(crystal[x][y] == true) output+="* ";
                        else output+="  ";
                    }
                }
            }
            output+="\n";
        }

        return output;
    }

    public int getIndexSize()
    {
        return index;
    }

    public boolean getMatrixValue(int x, int y)
    {
        return crystal[x][y];
    }

    private void drawCrystal()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 600);

        CrystalView drawing = new CrystalView(this);
        frame.add(drawing);
        frame.validate();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        (new CrystalModel(200)).drawCrystal();
    }

}
```

CrystalView.java

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class CrystalView extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    CrystalModel model;

    public CrystalView(CrystalModel m) {
        model = m;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        while (!model.runExperiment(1)) {
            for (int y = 0; y < model.getIndexSize(); y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < model.getIndexSize(); x++) {
                    if (model.getMatrixValue(x, y)) {
                        g.drawOval(x, y, 2, 2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I really appreciate it. However, try replacing you code in drawCrystal with while(this.runExperiment(1)) { System.out.println(this.toString()); } and call it in the main program like this: (new CrystalModel()).drawCrystal(); and it will display, in the terminal, exactly the right image. A textual representation of it. And there is no error in the logic, it simply works perfectly. And what I want to do is to draw EXACTLY that image, which is drawn perfectly by toString, but in a JPanel... So the error ought to be with the drawing code, not with the logic :/

Comment: I would be glad to help, but didn't get what you mean, sorry :) The 'drawing code' only puts some points to the JPanel. Points are there so it works now. The problem is all about which points it draws, right?

Comment: Just an advice - try to deactivate all your calculation and just put hardcoded values in drawing method (to get the desired picture). This will be a pure drawing with no logic, so somebody will be able to help you if the problem is really in drawing.